# Multiple PHP buttons? (One button is a submit button the other buttons are functions)

Tags: php, javascript, button

I'm making a php site that has multiple buttons.  One button saves, which requires it to be taken to a different page but the other buttons do simple things like add +1 to a score.

The function buttons are attached with javascript so the code looks like this for a function button:

```
<button onclick="addPoints(); ButtonStats()">Add</button></td>
```

I have tried multiple different ways to get the buttons working but I'm not sure how to do an if statement like this:

```
if ($_POST['SaveButton']) 
   $executestring = "location: process.php";
```

The if statement works for the save button (but clicking the other buttons currently refreshes the page).

So, how would I go about writing in the add button codes to an 'if' statement like that of the submit button?  (I've tried putting in addPoints() for the executestring but that didn't work so I'm just not sure how to write it out).

Comment: post more code its not enough

Comment: You tell us that you've tried multiple ways. Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: Hi there. Just so you know, there's no need to add `[solved]` tags to the title here; ticking the answer you prefer is enough to move the question out of unanswered screens `:)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `<button>` without the `type` *attribute* defined as `button`, cause they will try to submit the form, causing the page to be "refreshed". Use

```
<input type="button" value="click" />
```

or

```
<button type="button">Click</button>
```

if you don't want them to have the submit behavior.

Look at [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/dmfez/)

Answer (score -1):

You are calling javascript when button Add is clicked which means you can not do anything about it in php.
When you call javascript, all calculation is done on client side (for example users browser). Php is executed only when users comes to your page (because page is requested from server, server executes php and sends result).
It suggest you learn more about client side and server side languages.